# Track how many times a certain button has been pressed (in total by all users)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched for a long time after this answer but can't find anything to help me.

```
<button onclick="myFunction">Press Me</button>
<script>

    function myFunction(){
        //Adding 1 to the variable.
    }

</script>
```

How can I create a variable that stores how many times this button has been pressed in total by all users? I know you can use localStorage but that only saves how many times a *certain* person has clicked on the button. I want to see how many times it has been pressed in total by all users and make it into a variable.

Thanks

Comment: You need a file or database on the server. When a user clicks the button, send an AJAX request to the server, it can increment the counter.

Comment: You'll need a database so you can store the value.  You'll also need to take concurrency into account -- in other words, how do you accumulate your total if two users press the button at the same time.

Comment: You can also use google analytics or something similar.

Comment: Google analytics is the way to go